# How can I get top five elements that appears the most in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I already know how to get a element that appears the most in array but now I have a case where I need to get top 5 elements that appears most in the array.

**I have this array:**

```
[
  "fuji",
  "acros",
  "bombshell",
  "4za",
  "aerozine",
  "bianchi-milano",
  "bianchi-milano",
  "aerozine",
  "rapha",
  "rapha",
  "rapha",
  "100%",
  "100%",
  "100%",
  "100%"
];
```

**So top five should be:**

```
[
  "100%",
  "rapha",
  "bianchi-milano",
  "aerozine",
  "fuji" // This one can be random as all the rest appears only once
]
```

**And this is the code that I have for finding one that is duplicating the most:**

```
array.sort( (a, b) => arr.filter(v => v === a).length - arr.filter(v => v === b).length ) .pop();
```

Any help but also a clarification would mean a lot! Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: No! That will get all unique values but I need top one, sorted from the topest.

Answer (score 1):

```
const myArray = [
    'fuji',
    'acros',
    'bombshell',
    '4za',
    'aerozine',
    'bianchi-milano',
    'bianchi-milano',
    'aerozine',
    'rapha',
    'rapha',
    'rapha',
    '100%',
    '100%',
    '100%',
    '100%'
]
const sortByFrequency = (array) => {
    var frequency = {}

    array.forEach(function (value) { frequency[value] = 0 })

    var uniques = array.filter(function (value) {
        return ++frequency[value] == 1
    })

    return uniques.sort(function (a, b) {
        const y = frequency[b] - frequency[a]
        return y
    })
}
```

And then call this function:

`sortByFrequency(myArray).slice(0, 5)`

Comment: Thanks. I used your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need frequency of all words first and then get top 5
frequent ones (easier if you sort them first and then get top 5)

```
let a = [
  "fuji",
  "acros",
  "bombshell",
  "4za",
  "aerozine",
  "bianchi-milano",
  "bianchi-milano",
  "aerozine",
  "rapha",
  "rapha",
  "rapha",
  "100%",
  "100%",
  "100%",
  "100%"
];

let hashMap = {}
a.map(e=>{
   if(hashMap[e]) hashMap[e]++;
   else           hashMap[e]=1
})

let keys = Object.keys(hashMap);
let values = Object.values(hashMap);
let array = keys.map((e,i)=>({name:keys[i],value:values[i]}))
array.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
});
array.splice(-5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [
  "fuji",
  "acros",
  "bombshell",
  "4za",
  "aerozine",
  "bianchi-milano",
  "bianchi-milano",
  "aerozine",
  "rapha",
  "rapha",
  "rapha",
  "100%",
  "100%",
  "100%",
  "100%"
];

const totals = items.reduce((acc, item) => ({
  ...acc,
  [item]: acc[item] ? acc[item] + 1 : 1
}), {});

const totalsDesc = Object.keys(totals).sort(
  (item1,item2) => totals[item1] > totals[item2] ? -1 : 1
);

const result = totalsDesc.slice(0,5);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

See below

```
const list = ['j', 'b', 'c', 'tt', 'z', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'tt', 'tt'];

function Counter(array) {
  array.forEach(val => this[val] = (this[val] || 0) + 1);
}

console.log(new Counter(list));
```